# UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled Spark View Engine

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

Does  the UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled  feature of MVC3 work with other view engines beside Razor.
I would assume so but all examples I have seen are for Razor

I am currently using the Spark view engine.
I have set  in my web.conf appSettings..

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

I have added reference for dataannotations to the pages/namespaces section of Spark configuration

```
<add namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations"/>
```

I have included datannotations validation attributes on my model and 
tried to create a textbox 
 e.g Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name); in my view.

However the inputbox has no addition attributes. output is.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="name" id="name">
```

If I can get this working I  assume the [dataannotation extensions](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2011/02/23/introducing-data-annotations-extensions.aspx) should also work.

Comment: What attributes are you expecting to be on the `<input>`? Unobtrusive JavaScript means that the JavaScript will **not** be wired up as attributes of the tag but via JS after the page has loaded.

Comment: I think unobtrusive means use html5 attributes on the tag and wire the javascript up to them but I could be wrong. I  got it working  buy adding the Html.BeginForm helper,   J.W's answer was also correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any reason why unobtrusive javascript validation wouldn't work with other engines such as Spark (but cannot say for sure as myself I've never used it). Make sure you have placed this textbox inside a form generated with the `Html.BeginForm` helper.

Comment: Wow you guys are quick,  it was the missing  form,  I  was manually generating a form tags with a binding, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think those configuration controls how the html is rendered, so it should not matter which view engine you choose to use.